# How to load script below the footer with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add script below the footer, can I do it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("footer").html("<script>window.addEventListener('load', function() {new Options();}, false);</script>");
});
```

Comment: No, you can't inject script like that. ***However*** this example is completely pointless. If you want to execute some static code when the window loads just add it to a `script` tag in the HTML

Answer (score -1):

You can append the html tags, script tags after or before the html using the insertafter, insertbefore and append methods.

your code can be changed like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("footer").insertAfter("<script>window.addEventListener('load', function() {new Options();}, false);</script>");
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't tested this because 1) that's not what `insertAfter()` (or `insertBefore()` does) and 2) it still doesn't work. You cannot append a `script` tag like this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  we can use insert a script tag before and after using this code. I have tested this code.$(document).ready(function(){
    var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "../jquery.js";
$(s).insertAfter('button');
});